# How to change the visibility of a combobox in gridview

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change the visibility of a combobox in a gridview. 
When the value is empty or null then the combobox needs to be hidden.
This is my code so far. gvCursisten is the gridview.

Edit: This is working in xaml, but its not working in cs.

```
  <ListView Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="lvTest">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView x:Name="gvCursisten">
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Property" Width="160">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox x:Name="PropertyComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Voornaam}" Width="140" >
                                        <ComboBox.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=txtTest, Path=Text}" Value="Hoi">
                                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ComboBox.Style>
                                    </ComboBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>

C# code
GridViewColumn gvcCombobox2 = new GridViewColumn();
gvcCombobox2.Header = "Combobox2";
gvcCombobox2.Width = 200;

DataTemplate dteCombobox2 = new DataTemplate();

Style styleComboBox2 = new Style(typeof(ComboBox));
Setter setterStyleComboBox2 = new Setter();
setterStyleComboBox2.Property = ComboBox.VisibilityProperty;
setterStyleComboBox2.Value = Visibility.Visible;
styleComboBox2.Setters.Add(setterStyleComboBox2);

DataTrigger datatriggerStyleComboBox2 = new DataTrigger();
datatriggerStyleComboBox2.Value = "Hello";
Binding bindingDatatriggerStyleComboBox2 = new Binding("{Binding ControlType}");
datatriggerStyleComboBox2.Binding = bindingDatatriggerStyleComboBox2;

Setter setterDatatriggerStyleComboBox2 = new Setter();
setterDatatriggerStyleComboBox2.Property = ComboBox.VisibilityProperty;
setterDatatriggerStyleComboBox2.Value = Visibility.Hidden;
datatriggerStyleComboBox2.Setters.Add(setterDatatriggerStyleComboBox2);

styleComboBox2.Triggers.Add(datatriggerStyleComboBox2);

FrameworkElementFactory fefCombobox2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));
fefCombobox2.SetValue(ComboBox.WidthProperty, 140D);
fefCombobox2.SetValue(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, dtTest.DefaultView);
fefCombobox2.SetValue(ComboBox.StyleProperty, styleComboBox2);

dteCombobox2.VisualTree = fefCombobox2;
gvcCombobox2.CellTemplate = dteCombobox2;
gvCursisten.Columns.Add(gvcCombobox2);
```

Comment: See my edit for full C# solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I used System.Windows.Style to trigger a new style to the combobox.

```
 Style cbStyle = new Style(typeof(ComboBox));
                    Setter cbSetter = new Setter(ComboBox.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Visible);                  
                    cbStyle.Setters.Add(cbSetter);

                    DataTrigger cbDataTrigger = new DataTrigger();
                    Binding cbBinding = new Binding(column.ColumnName);

                    cbDataTrigger.Value = 0;

                    Setter cbDataSetter = new Setter(ComboBox.VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Hidden);

                    cbDataTrigger.Setters.Add(cbDataSetter);
                    cbDataTrigger.Binding = cbBinding;
                    cbStyle.Triggers.Add(cbDataTrigger);               

                    fElement.SetValue(ComboBox.StyleProperty, cbStyle);

                    DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
                    dataTemplate.VisualTree = fElement;
                    gvc.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept your solution so people that face the same issue that you faced find it

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to use [Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.behavior.behavior?view=netframework-4.7.2). You create a custom class that inherit from Behavior abstract class. When ItemsSource property is changed on ComboBox with binding it will trigger OnAttached() method of your Behavior class.

If you use xaml:

```
<Window //Your window property here
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">

<ComboBox x:Name="PropertyComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Voornaam}" Width="140" >
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:HideComboxBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ComboBox>
```

or if you prefer code behind:

```
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
[...]
Interaction.GetBehaviors(myCombobox).Add(new HideComboxBehavior());
```

Create custom class: **HideComboxBehavior.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

[...]

public class HideComboxBehavior : Behavior<ComboBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        if (AssociatedObject.Items == null || AssociatedObject.Items == 0)
            AssociatedObject.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;                               
    }
}
```

If the hidden ComboBox still take place on your layout and you don't want it then use instead Visibility.Collapsed

```
AssociatedObject.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

It is a clean solution and MVVM friendly. It avoid creating a variable binded to the ComboxBox Visibility property.

Comment: If i add Interaction.GetBehaviors(ComboBox).Add(new HideComboxBehavior()); i get a error " cannot convert from 'System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory to 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' because of FrameworkElementFactory fElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));

Comment: I think you won't be able to use behaviors with FrameworkElementFactory. By the way FrameworkElementFactory is deprecated way to programmatically create templates. Microsoft recommand : "to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class."

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarques

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You can loop through each row of your gridview and bind data or set visibility to your controls in gridview using FindControl.

```
protected void gvCursisten_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ComboBox cb = (e.Row.FindControl("gvcomboboxid") as ComboBox);
        if(some_value == null)
        {
            cb.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cb.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need a solution in C# not in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Only use `Value="{x:Null}"` instead of `Value="Hoi"`

```
`<ComboBox x:Name="PropertyComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Voornaam}" Width="140" 
  >
            <ComboBox.Style>
                 <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding 
  ElementName=txtTest, Path=Text}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                             <Setter Property="Visibility" 
   Value="Hidden"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </ComboBox.Style>
         </ComboBox>`
```

Comment: 1. Make sure there is no binding's issue.
2. Add breakpoint and check if value is null or its taking default value of string 
3. Can you show snippet of `txtTest` element.